# node.js mongodb projection ignored when there is a criterion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, monk

I am writing a node.js application using express, mongodb, and monk.

When I do a find with criteria only or with projections only, I get the expected result, but when I do a find with both, the full documents are returned, i.e., the projection is not performed.  My code looks like this:

```
var collection = db.get('myDB');  
collection.find({field1: "value"},{field2: 1, _id: 0},function(e,docs) {  
    ...do stuff with docs...  
});
```

It returns not just `field2` but all fields of all the docs matching the criterion on `field1`.  I can get `field2` from this, but I don't like the inefficiency of it.

Is there a way to use both criteria and projections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monk uses a space-delimited string for field projection where you prefix a field name with `-` to exclude it.

So it should be:

```
var collection = db.get('myDB');  
collection.find({field1: "value"}, 'field2 -_id', function(e,docs) {  
    ...do stuff with docs...  
});
```